# I'm getting an error with nginx, php and wordpress - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: juju, nginx, wordpress

Using the sample recipe I am deploying a WordPress solution on EC2:

```
juju bootstrap --constraints "instance-type=t1.micro"
juju set-constraints instance-type=t1.micro
juju debug-log
juju deploy mysql wordpress-db
juju deploy wordpress
juju add-relation wordpress wordpress-db
juju expose wordpress
```

After this I point my browser to the public url and get the error:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   nginx/1.1.19

Looking at the debug log I see this error:

```
2012-11-10 20:08:19,083 unit:wordpress/0: hook.output INFO:  * Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager php5-fpm
2012-11-10 20:08:20,267 unit:wordpress/0: hook.output INFO:    ...fail!
```

sshing to the WordPress box, I tried restarting the php service but I get a seg fault:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-194-31-77:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm start
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Anybody know the issue? Is there a problem with the php version and WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem with RAM. If you look on your wordpress hosts, they're likely running out of RAM quite quickly, and probably spraying 'out of memory' errors in `dmesg`. Thats because the default `tuning` setting of `single` does include a lot of plugins.

If you run `juju set wp-service-name tuning=bare` it will use less RAM and it might be able to survive on a t1.micro. If that still doesn't work, I'd recommend filing a bug against the charm here:

https://launchpad.net/charms/+source/wordpress/+filebug

And perhaps look into patching it to allow reducing the number of php5-fpm processes running or other things to save RAM in such a hyper-constrained environment.

Comment: Thanks that tuning trick seems to have fixed the issue!!!

Comment: Tyler, perhaps Accept the answer then, so this doesn't appear as an "unanswered" question?